# How to derive the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to derive the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of this matrix?
$$
C=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    c_0 & c_{N-1} & \cdots & c_2 & c_1 \\
    c_1 & c_0 & c_{N-1}&\cdots&c_2 \\
    \vdots & c_1 & c_0&\ddots&\vdots \\
    c_{N-2}&\vdots &\ddots&\ddots&c_{N-1}\\
c_{N-1}&c_{N-2}&\cdots&c_1&c_0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
\in \mathbb C^{N\times N}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). I think that should be enough information for you.

Comment: Thank you for your information.